# Sequelize use find where field is a CLOB

Tags: node.js, oracle, sequelize.js

I use Sequelize with Express for my web API project. I have an Oracle DB.

My current model is look like this

```
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const DatabaseModule = require('../modules/database.module');
const PortalModel = require('./portal.model');
const ModuleTypeModel = require('./module_type.model');

const constructor = {
    ID: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    TITLE: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    DESCRIPTION: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: false
    },
    PORTAL_ID: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
            model: PortalModel,
            key: 'ID'
        }
    },
    BACKGROUND_COLOR: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    MODULE_TYPE_ID: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
            model: ModuleTypeModel,
            key: 'ID'
        }
    },
    POSITION: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    }
}

const Module = DatabaseModule.define('MODULES', constructor, {
    tableName: 'MODULES',
    timestamps: false,
    createdAt: false,
    updatedAt: false
});

Module.belongsTo(PortalModel, { foreignKey: 'PORTAL_ID'});
Module.belongsTo(ModuleTypeModel, { foreignKey: 'MODULE_TYPE_ID'});
Module.addScope('references', {include: [{model: PortalModel}, {model: ModuleTypeModel}]});

Module.constructor = constructor;

DatabaseModule.sync();

module.exports = Module;
```

In my service, I call the FindAll function with a where :

```
/**
 * Return list of all modules
 * @returns {ModuleModel[]} 
 */
exports.getModules = async (description) => {
    const modules = await ModuleModel.findAll({where: {DESCRIPTION: description}});
    return modules;
}
```

when I try to retrieve data, it return me this :

```
DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
```

So my question is: how to use Sequelize find when the field wanted is a TEXT (CLOB) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the datatype for `DataTypes.TEXT` is translated to `CLOB`, you can't directly use `where: {<columnName>: value}`.
You can use `Sequelize.Op.like` operator:
Example:

```
// import Sequelize.Op
exports.getModules = async (description) => {
    const modules = await ModuleModel.findAll({where: {DESCRIPTION: { [Op.like]: description}}});
    return modules;
}
```

The other way would be using the raw query:

```
const modules = await DatabaseModule.query(`SELECT * FROM "MODULES" WHERE dbms_lob.compare(DESCRIPTION, to_clob(<description_character>)) = 0`);
```